# Asus ROG G751JM - Wireless network is very slow in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 14.10, asus

I have a dual booted configuration, with the default Windows 8.1, and the latest
Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit.

The wireless network is *very* slow. On Windows 8.1, it works like a charm, while
on Ubuntu, I get almost 1/8th of the original speed.

However, when I use Ethernet, I get the full download/upload speed that I'm supposed to have, just like Windows.

When I switch from ethernet to wireless, all the websites suddenly stop loading, and `apt-get` takes forever in starting the download.

Following [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/370783), here is the output :

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Jan 2015 14:59 IST +0530

Booted last: 21 Jan 2015 09:50 IST +0530

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
Codename:   utopic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.16.0-23-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 21 17:56:17 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0652]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

3c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:10a1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b414 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0b05:17fd ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0b05:17ac ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
asus_wmi               24094  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                13021  0 
ath9k                 136984  0 
ath9k_common           25638  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              446568  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    29052  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              660592  1 ath9k
cfg80211              510218  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
wmi                    19193  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
video                  20128  2 i915,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.6  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:332173 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:341601 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:398756806 (398.7 MB)  TX bytes:32561235 (32.5 MB)
          Interrupt:19 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.4  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:86 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:126178 (126.1 KB)  TX bytes:14213 (14.2 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"NETGEAR61"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'NETGEAR61' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-24 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:69   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Auto Ethernet] ------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.6
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

- Device: wlan0  [NETGEAR61] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             connected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           1 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *NETGEAR61:      Infra, <MAC 'NETGEAR61' [AC1]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 97 WPA2
    Photon Max 3G Wi-Fi_BD89: Infra, <MAC 'Photon Max 3G Wi-Fi_BD89' [AN2]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 9 WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.4
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/NETGEAR61]] (600 root)
[connection] id=NETGEAR61 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=NETGEAR61 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country CN: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20)
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (N/A, 30)
    (57240 - 59400 @ 2160), (N/A, 28)
    (59400 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 44)
    (63720 - 65880 @ 2160), (N/A, 28)

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

##### iwlist scan #######################

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'NETGEAR61' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-24 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"NETGEAR61"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000002aac9e0909
                    Extra: Last beacon: 56ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC '' [AC2]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=26/70  Signal level=-84 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:""
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001f88233184
                    Extra: Last beacon: 2268ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     F1B005F210401E25BEA4125
depends:        ath9k_hw,mac80211,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D1:20:C4:7C:14:BE:B6:2E:AD:67:03:D4:17:12:CC:11:05:75:D2:97
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     50297023DA06CB0C907A2CA
depends:        cfg80211,ath9k_hw,ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D1:20:C4:7C:14:BE:B6:2E:AD:67:03:D4:17:12:CC:11:05:75:D2:97
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     765883F7BDCD751661973EB
depends:        ath
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D1:20:C4:7C:14:BE:B6:2E:AD:67:03:D4:17:12:CC:11:05:75:D2:97
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     165C1DF76AF8C8B6A45DA4F
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D1:20:C4:7C:14:BE:B6:2E:AD:67:03:D4:17:12:CC:11:05:75:D2:97
sig_hashalgo:   sha512

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     0D5DBE66E4CC44B010DB516
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D1:20:C4:7C:14:BE:B6:2E:AD:67:03:D4:17:12:CC:11:05:75:D2:97
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     DEE8EAA48495E392CD51C2D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.16.0-23-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        D1:20:C4:7C:14:BE:B6:2E:AD:67:03:D4:17:12:CC:11:05:75:D2:97
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
nohwcrypt: 1
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf]
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0x10a1 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:0x0036 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[   13.299029] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   17.225704] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'NETGEAR61' [AC1]>
[   17.241172] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'NETGEAR61' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   17.245068] wlan0: authenticated
[   17.246828] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'NETGEAR61' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[   17.253065] wlan0: RX AssocResp from <MAC 'NETGEAR61' [AC1]> (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[   17.253112] wlan0: associated
[   17.253131] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   17.255059] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x809c
[   17.255060] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   17.255061] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   17.255062] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x52
[   17.255063] ath: Country alpha2 being used: CN
[   17.255064] ath: Regpair used: 0x52
[   17.255065] ath: regdomain 0x809c dynamically updated by country IE

########## wireless info END ############
```

I have followed almost every solution mentioned here on Ask Ubuntu and other websites, but neither of them seems to work.

Asus support has let me down. When I contacted them :

> For your case, that may be caused by lack of driver with it. (driver
>   is not compatible with linux Ubuntu )
>
> For your information, according to the support site:
>   http://support.asus.com.cn/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=G751JM&hashedid=H1PGPvZ0ODsnDxTf
>
> There is only win8.1 version driver for the notebook G751JM
>
> We don't recommend user to use linux Ubuntu OS with G751JM product.
>
> We passed your mail to technology R&D team, let them check and
>   consider to build it in the future.
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you very much for your
>   understanding
>
> Thank you for your support Asus product. Wish you have a good day.

How can I have a good day, knowing that the laptop I bought from my own savings is not compatible with my most used OS?

I will truly appreciate it if someone could point me to another solution for this problem. Is purchasing an external wireless network card is the only possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

for the Atheros card you can deactivate the hardware encryption of the driver. This will not affect the software encryption, like WPA2, etc:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

Comment: But the included script says that `nohwcrypt=1`, which means it's already disabled. That's because I've already tried this solution.

Comment: You might want to do the updates and see if the newer kernel helps